# When to add preservative to hot sauce?

Tags: sauce, storage-method, food-preservation, hot-sauce, ketchup

So I am currently trying on a recipe of homemade hot sauce, but I plan on adding either sodium benzoate or potassium sorbate as the preservative. I have figured out how much I would try using, but I am not quite sure about when I should add the preservative into my hot sauce. I have read of how: you dissolve the preservative with water before adding, but I am lost about when. My goal is to make it as similar to the commercial tomato ketchup (more viscous than the usual runny hot sauce), and I use xanthan gum as thickening agent. If I were to add the preservative mixture at the very last step (after heating process), I am afraid that the preservative liquid won't mix well with the already thickened hot sauce. So when (or to be precise, in which step) should I add the preservative into my hot sauce?

Comment: Welcome to SA!  That's a good but difficult question ... it make take folks a while to answer.

Answer (score -1):

You probably will need to add it to the water that you are adding to make the hot sauce to make sure the preservative dissolve thoroughly.

Comment: Welcome to SA!  Unfortunately, your answer doesn't really answer the OP's question: they want to know what stage of cooking to add it at, not whether to use water or not.

Comment: I am assuming that OP recipe has water in it like most sauce recipe. So the stage to add the preservative is when water is part of the recipe. It's also beneficial if the water used is hot, as it would accelerate the dissolving process of the preservative.

Comment: Mammo: that's a lot better, maybe re-word your answer?

Comment: Why would the rate of dissolution matter?  Once everything’s mixed, will that really be a problem?